# How do I fix my program that counts using an array, with increments of 25?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, for-loop, math

I have been trying to create a system that counts in increments of 25, like so:

When the last number in the array is 25, it is supposed to reset to 0, and add 1 to the previous position. Once all of the numbers in the array are equal to 25, an extra number is added the array (0), and all of the values in the array reset to 0.

This is meant to continue forever, but I am incapable of finding a solution myself, and the code I've written stops when the array reaches 4 values (see below). I've tried and searched stack, but cannot find any answers that suit my needs. I would appreciate somebody helping me with this, if anyone wants to challenge themselves with this small task.

I've tried a lot of different solutions, I know the answer is probably obvious. No automated solutions that use modules please, I am attempting to challenge myself and do it all with vanilla Python. Using Python 3.11. Here is my code, take a look if you want, but my solution might just seem irrational to you if you know what you're doing.

```
alpha = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
positions = [0, 0, 0, 0]

def all_25(items):
    return all(x == 25 for x in items)

def check_values():
    global positions
    if all_25(positions) == False:
        positions[-1] = 0
        if positions[-2] != 25:
            positions[-2] += 1
        else:
            positions[-2] = 0
            positions[0] += 1

    elif all_25(positions) == True:
        positions.append(0)
        positions = [0 for _ in positions]

    print(positions)

while True:
    print(positions)

    if positions[-1] == 25:
        check_values()
    
    positions[-1] += 1
```

## https://pastebin.com/iXaPVHDc

HERE IS MY CODE AND ALSO THE OUTPUT I GOT. I COULD NOT PUT IT ON THIS MESSAGE I DONT KNOW WHY ITS JUST NOT WORKING

Comment: I wonder, what is 'alpha' for in your example?

Comment: Good question. This program was originally intended to count using a bijective numeration system (aa, ab, ac, ad, ..., zzz), and i figured i could do this with numbers 0,25 (for the 26 letters of the alphabet) and then just use those numbers to create a string, indexing from the 'alpha' (alphabet) list.

Comment: Please check out the new answer to your question that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
def counter(m=25):
    '''
       m    -> maximum digit
       pool -> working sequence
       n    -> index of an element
       r    -> r == -len(pool)
    '''
    pool=[0]  
    m=m+1     
    n=-1      
    r=-1      
    while True:
        pool[n]+=1
        if pool[n]<m:
            n=-1
            print(pool)
        else:
            pool[n]=0
            if n==r:
                pool.insert(0,0)
                n=-1
                r=r-1
                print(pool) #for cases like [0,0,0]
            else:
                n=n-1
```